# Apollo Server Express: Request entity too large

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I need to POST a large payload in a GraphQL mutation. How do I increase the body size limit of Apollo Server?

I'm using `apollo-server-express` version 2.9.3.

My code (simplified):

```js
const myGraphQLSchema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      user: UserQuery,
    },
  }),
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: () => ({
      ...UserMutations,
    }),
  }),
});

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(schema: myGraphQLSchema);

const app = express();
app.use(apolloServer.getMiddleware({ path: '/graphql' });
```

Comment: I have the same issue but increasing body size doesn't help :(  The service can't handle so large input and the flow behaves strange

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly sure in which version it was added, but on 2.9.15 you can apply it in applyMiddleware function.

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(someConfig);
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  cors: {
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  },
  bodyParserConfig: {
    limit:"10mb"
  }
});
```

Comment: You are my angel ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Simply add an Express body parser before your Apollo server middleware:

```js
import { json } from 'express';

app.use(json({ limit: '2mb' });
app.use(apolloServer.getMiddleware({ path: '/graphql' });
```

---

If you want to get fancy, you can have a separate body size limit for authenticated vs unauthenticated requests:

```js
const jsonParsers = [
  json({ limit: '16kb' }),
  json({ limit: '2mb' }),
];

function parseJsonSmart(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  // How exactly you do auth depends on your app
  const isAuthenticated = req.context.isAuthenticated();
  return jsonParsers[isAuthenticated ? 1 : 0](req, res, next);
}

app.use(parseJsonSmart);
app.use(apolloServer.getMiddleware({ path: '/graphql' });
```